# Creating a chrome extension that allows you see HTML in all tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I was thinking about a project to study how Google Extensions works, here is my idea:
I want to create HTML that works in all tabs in the same moment.

Example: I'm in the first tab of Chrome and will have a button in an HTML element that when I press the button shows a div saying "Yes". When I switch the tab for the second, the idea is the div saying "Yes" will continue in the same place.

The best scenario for me is the same DIV that are in the first tab will be the same in the second.

For this project I need to know if it is possible and how do and start to do this,

Thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: web sockets maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this.  Hopefully this will be useful

```
$(window).on('storage', message_received);  // set listener event
function message_received(ev) {   // listener function
    var message = ev.originalEvent.newValue;
    // if(message.Action ==   // do whatever
}


function message_broadcast(message) { // sending function
        localStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify(message));
    localStorage.removeItem('message');
}

message_broadcast({ "Action": "FileDeleted", "FileType": docType }); // send an object to the listener
```